# Any possibility to change BIOS default values?

Tags: bios, power

is there any possibility to change some BIOS default values? I am talking about the power management, I want the computer to power on by default after a power loss. This is because in case of an headless system if there is some kind of issue with the CMOS battery, BIOS will restore default settings (which is power off after power loss), thus not starting anymore..
It's an AMI BIOS on Asus UN45 model in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **is there any possibility to change some BIOS default values?**

No in general. That sort of default-value set for BIOS settings is likely to be constants in the firmware ROM (or equivalent), not data in some reprogrammable IC.

Yes if you have the money and time to make special arrangements with a BIOS maker + motherboard maker and anticipate buying tens or hundreds of thousands of units.